# left operand must be l-value

Tags: c++

Я хочу неизвестному типу указателя присвоить `void *`, т.е.

```
int i = 5;
void* iptr = &i;
int* ptr;
ptr = iptr;
```

Получаю ошибку невозможности привидения. Пытаюсь привести тип к `void *`

```
(void *)ptr = iptr;
```

Однако снова получаю ошибку, но немного другую: `left operand must be l-value`. **Почему в таком случае левая часть становится** `r-value`?
Далее я сделал что-то такое

```
*(void**)&ptr = iptr
```

и все заработало. **Однако что это значит я до конца не понимаю**. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Comment: Если вы хотите положить в переменную `int*` значение `void*`, вам надо не переменную кастить к `void*`, а значение к `int*`.

Comment: Не понял. Почему на вопросе стоит тэг C? В С можно просто `ptr = iptr`. Никакого явного приведения как в `void *` так и из `void *` делать не надо.

Comment: Что именно имеется в виду под  "неизвестным типом указателя"? (Учитывая, что С и С++ - жестко типизированные компилируемые языки программирования.)

Answer (score 3):

Результат приведения типа *всегда* является rvalue (за исключением случая приведения к ссылочному типу в С++). Почему вас это удивляет - не ясно. Целевой тип приведения в общем случае не имеет ничего общего с исходным типом. Как тут может получиться lvalue? С каким объектом в памяти это lvalue будет связано?

Вариант `*(void**)&ptr` не является "приведением типа" вообще. Это попытка *переинтерпретации* памяти указателя `int *ptr` как объекта типа `void *`. Такая переинтерпретация приводит к неопределенному поведению.

Если вы хотите в указатель `int *ptr` занести значение указателя `void *iptr` (что за странная схема именования?), то приведение типа тут возможно такое

```
ptr = (int *) iptr;
// или
ptr = static_cast<int *>(iptr);
```

Однако в языке С и этого не нужно

```
ptr = iptr;
```

ибо в С преобразования указателей как в `void *`, так и из `void *` делаются неявно.

Comment: тег `c` тут действительно был не нужен, но уже не важно :-). Дело в том, что мне нужно присвоить тип `void*` к неизвестному типу указателя. Приводя тип справа, я должен знать тип слева, который я не знаю. Я в вопросе это написал. Если мне нужно сделать переинтерпретацию, как это сделать безопасно?

Comment: вот поэтому работа с void* небезопасна...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan как тогда безопасно сделать, если не знаешь тип указателя к которому приводить будешь?

Comment: @elvy можете привести пример, когда не знаешь тип указателя? `iptr = static_cast<decltype(iptr)>(ptr);`

Comment: @vegorov макросы.

Comment: @elvy: Ну так тем не менее, если вы можете использовать `decltype(iptr)` - это считается, что тип указателя "известен" или нет?

Comment: @elvy А исходная задача, которую Вы хотите решить макросами, она какая?  Что у вас не получается без макросов? Какой сценарий?

Answer (score 1):

Задавая вопрос, вы свалили в кучу теги `С++` и `С`, что в данном конкретном случае, неправильно - в этих языках принят разный синтаксис явного преобразования типов. `C++`, в виду обратной совместимости, поддерживает синтаксис `С`, но пользоваться им неудобно.

**Вам нужно приводить тип не того, *куда* вы хотите что-то записать, а того, *что* вы хотите записать.**

Таким образом, на C++:

```
int i = 5;
void* iptr = &i;
int* ptr;
ptr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(iptr);
```

Этот синтаксис вполне явно указывает, что (`iptr`) и к какому типу (`int*`) надо приводить.

Сишные скобочки из 80x же могут сыграть с вами злую шутку, однако в данном случае, нужно ими пользоваться вот так:

```
int i = 5;
void* iptr = &i;
int* ptr;
ptr = (int*)iptr;
```

То, как вы поступили тоже будет работать, однако создает трудности в понимании кода. Кроме того, вы не сможете написать более качественный код с использованием `const`:

```
int i = 5;
void* iptr = &i;
const int* ptr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(iptr);
```

Answer (score 1):

То, чего вы хотите добиться, может приводить к серьёзным проблемам.

`@AR Hovsepyan` в комментарии уже написал Вам про это:

> вот поэтому работа с void* небезопасна...

Пример, где происходит разыменование `int*` как `double*`, то есть по факту будет попытка прочитать по некоторому адресу байт больше, чем там на самом деле есть(проинициализировано)

Я не знаю точно что это - UB или нет, но это очевидно ошибка.

```
#include <iostream>
static int N = 2;
static int* iptr = &N;

static double D = 15.0;
static double* dptr = &D;

int* getPtr(int i){
    (void)i;
    return iptr;
}
double* getPtr(double d){
    (void)d;
    return dptr;
}

int main()
{

    int n = 5;
    void* ptr = &n;
    auto iptr = getPtr(1);
    iptr = static_cast<decltype(iptr)>(ptr);    //ok, типы свопадают
    std::cout << *iptr << std::endl;
    auto dptr = getPtr(1.0);
    dptr = static_cast<decltype(dptr)>(ptr);    //error, int* -> double*
    std::cout << *dptr << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что вы фактически приводите **значение** указателя `ptr` к типу `void*`. Получается что-то вроде

```
0xDEADBEEF = iptr;
```

Во втором случае вы берете адрес переменной `ptr`, приводите его (адрес!) к `void**`, и при разыменовании получаете *переменную по этому адресу* типа `void*`.